# Problem with Wifi Access Point Scan

Tags: networking, network-manager, scanner

I am using `iw` command to scan available SSID and corresponding signal strength for the purpose of indoor localization. However, there are too many access points. I can try to trim down the list by filtering SSID. However, it is a post-processing, and it takes some time (1-2 seconds). Is there any way to utilize `iw` with specific SSID such that acquiring signal strength will be much faster? Or is there any library that I can use to write a customized scanner for specific SSID?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the Aircrack suite. From that suite you can use airodump-ng. This is an example:

Let's filter by the SSID **DummyWifi**:

```
airodump-ng --essid DummyWifi wlan0
```

And wlan0 is the name of your wifi adapter.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the suite. However, it seems that using the suite will disable connection with wifi. Is there any other way to monitor BSSID signal?

Comment: You can user another adapter or use one that supports monitor mode.